# Apache acts like has reached to the maximum client but it is not

Tags: apache, lamp

Apache acts like has reached to the maximum client value and I can't see even default apache's "works" page but it is not. I can see that from server-status. It is also a development server and restricted with intranet. So, not possible.

I also re-defined ServerLimit and reduced timeout value, turned off keepalive in Apache's config but nothing change. What would you suggest ?

A few extra info :

It is a virtual machine ( VmWare )

Ram amount : 512 Mb / Actual usage ~150mb

CPU : 1 x 2.40 ghz / Load : 0.00-0.050

Apache version is 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- check the logs
- Apache creates one new child process per second, only one. Try to increase `StartServers` and `MinSpareServers`. If you know how many apache child you can put in your memory put that number for `MinSpareServers`, `MaxSpareServers`, `StartServers` and `MaxClients`
- 512M is short. If one Apache process takes 64M (usually it's around 20MB, but with things like Drupal we sometimes see 128M per process), then you can only handle 512/64=8 child process, so a MaxClient=8. If you tell Apache that the MaxClient is 150, then give it some RAM to handle that, or check that your application is not eating too much RAM.